# Foreach in laravel 4 Controller rendering in View

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing a booking system for my webapp.
I get the output I want in my Controller with print_r.
Unfortunately I have not been able to get the right output in my View.

```
$userId = Sentry::getUser()->id;
$my_garden = DB::select('select * from gardens where userId = ?',array($userId));
foreach($my_garden as $garden)
{
   $gardenId = $garden->id;
   $address = $garden->address;
   $bookings_in_my_garden = Garden::find($gardenId)->booking;
   print_r($address.'<br>');
   foreach($bookings_in_my_garden as $bookings)
   {
       print_r($bookings->dateFrom." - ".$bookings->dateTo.'<br>');
    }
}
```

The output I get is 
Predikerinnenstraat 10
2013-11-05 - 2013-11-12
Prinsenstraat 2
2013-11-30 - 2013-12-07
2013-11-20 - 2013-11-27
and is correct
But when I pass it to my view like so:

```
return View::make('admin.booking.index')
->with('my_garden',$my_garden)
->with('bookings_in_my_garden',$bookings_in_my_garden);
```

and call

```
@foreach($my_garden as $garden)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $garden->id }}</td>
           @foreach($bookings_in_my_garden as $bookings)
                <td>{{ $bookings->dateFrom }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            @endforeach
        <td>{{ $garden->address }}</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I end up with
2   2013-11-30          2013-11-20          Predikerinnenstraat 10
8   2013-11-30          2013-11-20          Prinsenstraat 2


Someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to your view only the last booking.

You have some options, here are two of them:

1) Create a [Eloquent Relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) between them, so you can in your view:

```
@foreach($my_garden as $garden)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $garden->id }}</td>
           @foreach($garden->bookings as $booking)
                <td>{{ $booking->dateFrom }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            @endforeach
        <td>{{ $garden->address }}</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

2) Store them all in an array in the controller and pass to your view.